# why run both of confirmation of if()else in javascript?whats solution?

Tags: javascript, block, confirmation

I write code to check a form and if user enter all of information run confirm that show " are you sure to submit?".i use this for two form in onclick attribute.
My code is same this:

```
Var strurl=window.location.search();
 If(strurl.search("click=edit")>0)
  {
 If(document.forms["frm"]["fname"].value="")
 { alert("please enter all information required");
  Return false;
}

Return Confirm("are you sure to submit?");

}
Else
{

If(document.forms["frm"]["tel_num"].value="")
  { alert("please enter all information required");
 Return false;
  }

Return Confirm("are you sure to submit?");



}
```

This code is for two form that one of these form show in one condition and dont show both form by php programming.

But my problem is run both confirm in both form and i couldnt block one of them in another form.

I know that can seperate to two page but for a reason i should use these codes in one page.

What should i do to solve this?

Comment: Your code is invalid with all that capitalization. Are you on an iPhone or something?

Comment: Wrap your code in a function (rather than letting it run globally) and bind the function to the submit event of each form. This will ensure each form doesn't affect the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.:-) I call twice this function.I found that between 1000 line of codes after 5 hours search.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace all the title case of the Function like (Confirm), Return, Var and If Else in lowercase.
2. `.search` should be `.indexOf("click=edit")>-1`
3. Please properly indent your code, it will give you a better understanding.

```js
var strurl = window.location.search();
if(strurl.indexOf("click=edit") > -1) {
  if(document.forms["frm"]["fname"].value = "") {
    alert("please enter all information required");
    return false;
  }
  return confirm("are you sure to submit?");
}

else {
  if(document.forms["frm"]["tel_num"].value = "") {
    alert("please enter all information required");
    return false;
  }
  return confirm("are you sure to submit?");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but run both confirm again.yes you'r right.these uppercases is beacause of typing in text area to create my question and all if ,return and confirm have lowercase.  Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: I found the problem.:-) i cal twice this function.i found that between 1000 line programming after 5 hours search, yes codewizard,I use tablet.